# How much damage should a character do when flung with Sonic Thrust?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

I'm building a Skyrim-y dragon and settled on [Sonic Thrust](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/sonic-thrust) for Fus Ro Dah. in the event that I am positioned to fire one player at another I'm looking for input on the damage dealt.

"Other objects cause damage ranging from 1 point per 25 pounds (for less dangerous objects) to 1d6 points of damage per 25 pounds (for hard, dense objects)."

Assuming that I fling one player at another, and they both weigh ~200lbs, should they both take 8d6 dmg (and likely fall prone) Or should the damage be based on the weight and armor type of the opposing number?

Opinions?

Comment: Per my answer, the rules say that creatures do not deal damage when hurled. Is this the question asked? Or do you understand what the rules say, and desire opinions on a houserule that will allow *sonic thrust* to deal damage with hurled creatures?

Comment: What you seem to be looking for is more of an Opinion on how you believe something should act, not solid facts as supported by the rules. If you're looking to homebrew something you should emulate your spell effect based on other spells a PC may have access to at their level.

Comment: @KRYan, I had it in my mind that a character which, when thrown, would behave similarly to an armored sack of potatoes. So, without control over its own movement would behave similarly to an object.

Comment: Mr sandwich,  I am looking for an opinion on this, yes. My intent is to find a balanced execution of this as a spell based on Sonic Thrust.

Comment: @user36708 That is not* what the rules say. The question is unclear whether you are seeking a rules clarification, or seeking houserule suggestions. Please clarify.

Comment: House rule suggestion, then. I'm inclined to agree with Gatherer's conclusion, below. :/

Comment: Please clarify this desired approach in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Note:  I am unable to find a definition of "object" in the rules that differs from its [dictionary definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/object), and therefore assume that creatures are also objects.  Note that if the creature you're flinging is immaterial, none of this answer applies.)

The damage to the character being flung is fairly clear:  between no damage and 1d6 damage is all that's appropriate.  The spell specifically calls out the damage to a hurled creature, although a "solid surface" could be more clearly defined.

PFSRD:

> If a hurled creature is thrown against a solid surface, it takes damage as if it had fallen 10 feet (1d6 points).

The damage to the target the first creature is being flung at is also pretty clear:  between 1 and 1d6 per 25 pounds of the creature you threw at it.  In your example, anywhere from 8 to 8d6 is appropriate.

The hard part is gauging where in those ranges to actually place the damage.  I can only tell you how I would probably handle it at my own table, so what follows is not hard rules from the books but my personal opinion based on my reading of the spell and GM experience:

Particularly light (in density, not weight) characters, such as unarmored halflings and most waterborne, airborne, or elemental races, should do the minimum:  1 point per 25 pounds.  "Normal" density characters, such as most unarmored or lightly armored PCs, should do around 1d3 damage per 25 pounds.  Denser, but still not solid characters, including dwarves in no or light armor and normal characters in medium armor, should do 1d4 per 25 pounds.  The most solid characters, such as dwarves in medium armor or any character in heavy armor, should do the full 1d6 per 25 pounds.

The above estimates are good for determining whether the hurled character should take their d6 damage or not, too.  If they hit a creature that would do d6's, they take a d6 for hitting a "solid" object (and stop in the square before the creature, like they would when they hit a wall).  If the creature they struck wasn't that solid, they don't take that damage, and they land in a random square around the creature, as if you'd missed.  (If you *actually* miss, they should take 1d6 from hitting the ground.)

Answer (score 4):

### Technically, the spell [*sonic thrust*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/sonic-thrust) deals damage *only* to a hurled object's *target*, not to the hurled creature or object itself...

Most interpretations separate creatures and objects into two distinct categories. For example, on [Aiming a Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell) says

> Some spells have a target or targets. You cast these spells on creatures or objects, as defined by the spell itself.

So, assuming the GM is differentiating between creatures and objects,<sup>1</sup> the spell [*sonic thrust*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/sonic-thrust) says

> You can use this spell to hurl an object or creature toward a particular target. You must succeed on attack rolls (one per creature or object thrown) to hit the target with the items, using your base attack bonus + your Intelligence modifier (if a wizard) or Charisma modifier (if a bard or sorcerer). **Hurled weapons cause standard damage** (with no Strength bonus; note that arrows or bolts deal damage as daggers of their size when used in this manner). **Other objects cause damage** ranging from 1 point per 25 pounds (for less dangerous objects) to 1d6 points of damage per 25 pounds (for hard, dense objects). **Objects and creatures that miss their target land in a square adjacent to the target.**

Emphasis mine. Using the spell as written, only a hurled **object** *causes* damage, hurled **creatures**, sadly, *don't*. Also, the hurled creature or object doesn't *suffer* any damage itself from being hurled at a target. The effect of being hurled is that the hurled creature or object is (probably) farther away (which, in the case of an opposing creature, is still usually a good thing). Such an experience doesn't even render a hurled creature prone. (I *know*, right?)

The caster can, instead, if he desires, deal damage to a hurled creature by slamming the hurled creature into a solid surface:

> If a hurled creature is thrown against a solid surface, it takes damage as if it had fallen 10 feet (1d6 points).

Unfortunately, *other creatures* aren't solid surfaces.

### ...But the GM can fix that with a house rule

I mean, seriously, you're playing a Wiz9 who can *teleport* if he wants. At that point, really, hurting monsters by playing pool with them *should* be a thing. I suggest, were the GM to make a house rule that allows a hurled creature to deal damage to a target as if the hurled creature were an object that an adventurer count as a hard, dense object.<sup>2</sup>

I'd advocate against both hurled *and* target taking damage, though. Just cast *fireball*.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> Yes, I know what happens when one assumes.
<sup>**2**</sup> Except a monk, which would count as a less dangerous object.

Comment: "a hard, dense object" -- or put them somewhere in the middle of the scale between candy floss and depleted uranium shells.

Comment: @SteveJessop It's how you know folks are still paid by the word.